# sum(map()) function not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having some trouble with my code. I need to count how many values in the list are lower than 20. The problem is that my list has both `str` and `int` values.

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
from numpy import mean
import sys

mylistidade = []
mylistmen = []
mylistwomen = []

count = sum(map(lambda x : x<20, mylistwomen[1::2]))

for x in range (1, 5):
    print(f'----- {x}ª PESSOA -----')
    nome = str(input('Nome: ')).strip().title()
    idade = int(input('Idade: '))
    sexo = str(input('Sexo [M/F}: ')).upper()
    if sexo == 'M' or sexo == 'F':
        pass
    else:
        print('Digite um valor válido no campo Sexo!')
        sys.exit()
    if sexo == 'M':
        mylistmen.append(nome)
        mylistmen.append(idade)
    else:
        mylistwomen.append(nome)
        mylistwomen.append(idade)
   
    mylistidade.append(idade)
   
print(mylistmen)
print(mylistwomen)
print(f'The average age for the group is {mean(mylistidade)}!')
position = mylistmen.index(max(mylistmen[1::2]))
print(f'The oldest man has {max(mylistmen[1::2])} years and it is called', end=' ')
print(f'{mylistmen[position-1]}')
print(f'There is {count} women that has less than 20 years!')
```

I would like to stick with my solution of `sum(map())`. Just need some help to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: what is not working? If you add more detail to your question it will help people answer it.

Comment: Sure. The output of the last line is always zero. The count parameter is returning zero even though some inputs in the list are less than 20.

Comment: ... because you are always using empty lists... Why did you *expect* something other than 0?

Comment: Actually the lists are not empty. In the lines mylistwomen.append(nome) and mylistwomen.append(idade) the inputed values are being added to the list mylistwomen

Comment: Add more detail **to your question** by editing it.

Comment: ... that is irrelevant, they are empty when you execute `sum(map(lambda x : x<20, mylistwomen[1::2]))`

Comment: Yeah, but that was what I was missing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move count under the for loop

```
from numpy import mean
import sys

mylistidade = []
mylistmen = []
mylistwomen = []

for x in range (1, 5):
    print(f'----- {x}ª PESSOA -----')
    nome = str(input('Nome: ')).strip().title()
    idade = int(input('Idade: '))
    sexo = str(input('Sexo [M/F}: ')).upper()
    if sexo == 'M' or sexo == 'F':
        pass
    else:
        print('Digite um valor válido no campo Sexo!')
        sys.exit()
    if sexo == 'M':
        mylistmen.append(nome)
        mylistmen.append(idade)
    else:
        mylistwomen.append(nome)
        mylistwomen.append(idade)
   
    mylistidade.append(idade)

count = sum(map(lambda x : x<20, mylistwomen[1::2]))
   
print(mylistmen)
print(mylistwomen)
print(f'The average age for the group is {mean(mylistidade)}!')
position = mylistmen.index(max(mylistmen[1::2]))
print(f'The oldest man has {max(mylistmen[1::2])} years and it is called', end=' ')
print(f'{mylistmen[position-1]}')
print(f'There is {count} women that has less than 20 years!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
count = sum(map(lambda x : x if type(x)== 'int' and x<20, mylistwomen[1::2]))